# Programmatically add content to a TableLayout on Android

Tags: android, layout, tablelayout

I am trying to add rows to a table after a click to a button (so after the generation of the activity).

My XML code is:

```
       <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1"
            android:id="@+id/result_table">
            <TableRow 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    style="@style/MyHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Col1" />
                <TextView
                    style="@style/MyHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Col2"  />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

So when I load the activity I have my table with my only row. Then when I click on my button I do:

```
    resultTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.result_table);

    LayoutParams rowLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LayoutParams cellLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TableRow tableRow;
    TextView cellValue;
    for(Asdf a : as) {
        tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowLayoutParams);

        cellValue = new TextView(this);
        cellValue.setText(a.getText());
        cellValue.setLayoutParams(cellLayoutParams);
        cellValue.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.MyText);
        tableRow.addView(cellValue);

        cellValue = new TextView(this);
        cellValue.setText("asdf");
        cellValue.setLayoutParams(cellLayoutParams);
        cellValue.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.MyText);
        tableRow.addView(cellValue);

        resultTable.addView(tableRow);
    }

    resultTable.invalidate();
```

But it doesn't add anything, and I am sure about that the loop iterates. I don't get any warning/exception in the logcat.

Can you help me please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the `LayoutParams` for the added `Views` like this:

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TableRow.LayoutParams cellLayoutParams = TableRow.new LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```